# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes --- I am getting this error on importing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[image]

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I am getting this error whenever I import matplotlib in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is all what I did. I am getting this error whenever I import matplotlib.